# Are 4 colors necessary to properly color adjacent countries of congruent shape?

Tags: geometry, coloring

The four color theorem proved that at most 4 colors are necessary to properly color any map (countries sharing a border have different colors). My question is the following:

Does there exist a map with 4 countries of congruent shape (same shape and same size, rotations and translations allowed) such that 4 colors are necessary to color this map?

Comment: Actually the four color theorem states that the chromatic number of any looples, planar graph is at most $4$. Your statement is not necessarily true, depending on what "map" means. First, a solution: create a map out of a square, by dividing it into 4 squares: ⊞. The middlepoint is shared by all countries, it satisfies your properties and it generates a planar graph. Note that this trick cannot be used with more than 4 countries (all sharing a single point) because a graph generated from such a map is not planar. And so such "maps" cannot be colored with only 4 colors.

Comment: Generally, if two countries meet only at a single point, they are allowed to have the same color, so I think OP will reject your example.

Comment: There are examples if you don't insist on the four countries being connected, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem#/media/File:4CT_Non-Counterexample_1.svg

Comment: See also [this Puzzling SE post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/58751/20814)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't mind there being (uncoloured) areas between the countries, and allow reflection as well as rotation/translation, then the following is an example:

[image: four-coloured map]

I suspect it is also possible without using reflection, but don't think it is possible without having any uncoloured areas between the countries. I could well be wrong about that, given such crazy things like the [Voderberg tile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voderberg_tiling) that is surrounded by two copies of itself (which touch only at a single point so not sufficient here).

Edit:
Here is one with symmetric countries, so no reflection is needed. There is now only one uncoloured region with a much smaller area.
[image]